# Recurring contributions cancelled in Civi NOT cancelled in Authorize.net

Tags: contributions

Anyone having issues with recurring contributions being cancelled in Civi not being communicated to authorize.net in 4.7.9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this was an issue caused by the iATS extension - strange as that may sound - you will find details at the following link: https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm/issues/188

Whether or not the cancel recurring for PayPal ever worked is a separate question altogether (for us it never has).

Answer (score 0):

Eileen McNaught and Joe McLaughlin have both indicated that apparently this has never worked - we must be in possession of some custom code that made this work in 4.4.7 and earlier, but apparently it is no longer functioning in 4.7.X - thanks for your help!

Comment: And Tamar, FYI, this is another reason I'm accelerating our move to iATS for payment processing.

Comment: I'm not sure this is accurate... I have at least one client on 4.5.5 for whom this functionality works just fine without any customization at all.  I believe I have some others for whom this works as well (we have not moved any clients to 4.7.x as yet).